# SCSS Scoped Import

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

like the title, I'm trying to import an SCSS file inside others in order to stylize them.
That import should be "scoped".

Maybe with some codes, I'll explain myself better.

File A

```css
ion-content {
  --padding-end: 10px;
  --padding-start: 10px;
}
```

File B:

```css
@import "../style.scss"
```

The problem is that the file B is an overlay, so when the overlay will be closed, the `ion-content` will have the same style as `File B`.

There is any solution for this problem without using `classes`?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly in this case you could use css global specificity to put global styles in A and overrides in file B. Scope = global cascade.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I can't stylize global styles, probably there would be regression

Comment: Yes but you can override them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

I found a solution just valid `Ionic 5` (tested), but I think is still valid for the other versions of the framework and `Angular` version too.

The solution is pretty easy:

File A component

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-component-a",
  templateUrl: "component-a.html",
  styleUrls: ["./component-a.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // ADD THIS FOR ENCAPSULATION
})
```

So, in the file A style:

```
app-component-a {
  @import "../style.scss"
}
```

In this way, the style will not be applied to the entire app with the same elements but just for that component.